# Java doesn't split "|" symbol correctly

Tags: java, split

I have a file with content

1|yes|
2|yes|
3|yes|
4|yes|
5|yes|
6|yes|
7|yes|
8|yes|
9|yes|
10|yes|
11|yes|
12|yes|
13|yes|
14|yes|
15|yes|

I use java's `String[] tokens = split("|")`; to split each line, but it returns (for example splitting "10|yes|") [1,0,|,y,e,s,|]. It seems instead of splitting by "|", it splits every character. Anyone has any idea on it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` accepts a *regular expression*. `|` has a specific meaning in regular expressions, it expresses an *alternation*. To actually split on `|`, you have to escape it in the regex with a backslash. Since you specify the regex using a string literal, and backslashes are special in string literals, you have to escape *that* with another backslash:

```
String[] tokens = str.split("\\|");
```

In the general case, if you want to use the contents of a string literally, you can use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) to automatically escape any special characters. You don't really need it here, but it's useful for end-user-entered values:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(Pattern.quote(stringToSplitOnLiterally));
```

Comment: Thanks T.J.! Just tried it out. It is working now and thanks for explaining!